# Multi-tenancy in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, data-modeling, multi-tenant

We are supporting multi-tenancy. Is it better to have customer id as part of partition key or clustering column

Having customer id as part of partition key will ensure that one customers data cannot be viewed by another customer.

Having customer id as part of clustering column, developers have to ensure that customer id is part of where clause. Also takes up more space.

Is there one better way over the other ? 
There will impact on time-series data, since data will be partitioned by customer id and the super user having access to all customers will not be able to view time-series data correctly.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have customer_id as a *part* of your partition key.  You'll need this to ensure that each customer's data is stored together.

However, make sure that customer_id is *not* the only partition key.  If you have a time series data set with millions of rows, you won't want to attempt to store them all in the same partition (it'll get too big).

> There will impact on time-series data, since data will be partitioned by customer id and the super user having access to all customers will not be able to view time-series data correctly.

This comes back to designing your tables with a query-based approach.  If you have a query requirement to support queries on time series data for all (or multiple) customers at once, then you may need a table designed to support that.

Comment: Why would be there an impact on time-series data? Can you please explain, why wouldn't the super user having access to all customers be able to view time-series data correctly?

Comment: @simo because Cassandra doesn't sort result sets.  Using a time component as a clustering key will order the data by time *within* the partition key.  Therefore, I assume that what the OP meant when he said "not able to view time-series data correctly" was that a super user querying data for multiple customers at once (something I don't recommend) would find the result set ordered by `customer_id` and not by write-time itself.

Comment: I see now, but my case is different, as I will querying data for single customer, thus, I expect to view the data correctly ordered by time clustering key, is this a correct assumption?